# Selecting filtered cells only

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter a colour on column which works, then I want Excel to select all the cells that are filtered. However I don't want it to select the first row. I want Excel to skip copying if the filtered are empty, if not then carry on.

So far I have the following (the different R,G,B codes are for colour filtering and Colour is the name of the worksheet I can feed in):

```
    Sub ColourWork(Colour As String, RCode As String, GCode As String, BCode As String)

        Dim rCopy As Range

        'Q1======

        Sheets("Combine").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AJ").AutoFilter

        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AJ$493").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=RGB(RCode, GCode, BCode), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

        'here is the issue! Because it cannot copy/select nothing! 

        On Error GoTo Error1
        Set rCopy = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Copy

        Sheets(Colour).Select

        If IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) = True Then

            Range("$A$2").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        Else

            Range("$A$2").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        End If

Point1:

Error1:

GoTo Point1

End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want it to not copy all of the row if one or more of the columns is empty?

Comment: So if its filtered, it used to select all the rows (filtered or unfiltered)... what am doing is checking one column seeing if there are any of green colour then trying to copy thoes rows if any, if not then continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Sub ColourWork(Colour As String, RCode As String, GCode As String, BCode As String)
    Dim rCopy As Range
    Sheets("Combine").Select
    With [a:aj].AutoFilter(8, RGB(RCode, GCode, BCode), xlFilterCellColor)
        Set rCopy = .Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Sheets(Colour).Select
        [index(a:a,1+max(iferror(match({"*";9E+99},a:a,{-1;1}),1)))].Paste
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... Set rCopy = ActiveSheet.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy  ---------- I had to change the line so that it was activesheet and the offset by (1, 0) however when I run still get an error regarding this line: "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Answer (score 1):

Use `Specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)` for that, e.g.

```
    Set rCopy = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).Copy
```

For a little more on that, check my blog post on specialcells [here](https://tduhameau.wordpress.com/tag/specialcells/).

Comment: Still an error, ive put test data in, and it doesnt show up still says its empty

Answer (score 0):

Reminds me of some code I wrote a while ago.  It's not tailored to do exactly what you're asking (directly copying or acting on colors), but it's a very handy tool for the general case of handling filter row gaps.

What it does: Populates a field named "F" in the first ListObject (Table) in a sheet with a value 0 if the row is hidden, or 1 if the row is visible.  If no column/field "F" exists, one gets created and added at the right end of the table.  Then It clears all sheet filters, sorts column F so all visible rows come to the top, then re-filters.  The result is that you get all your filtered values together without gaps in between.  A secondary effect is that you can save a complex combination of filters by renaming the "F" column/field.

Disclaimer:  I wrote this code a while ago and I'm sure there's room for improvement. It's served my purpose though, so I just haven't taken the time. let me know if you come up with anything better.

```
Sub Filter_By_Sorting()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim r As Double
Dim C As Double
Dim A As Worksheet
Set A = ActiveSheet
r = A.ListObjects(1).ListRows(1).Range.Row
On Error Resume Next
C = A.Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name & "[F]").Column
    If Err <> 0 Then
         C = A.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(A.ListObjects(1).ListColumns.Count).Range.Column + 1
         Columns(C).Select
         Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
         Cells(A.ListObjects(1).ListRows(1).Range.Row - 1, C) = "F"
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
Dim end_r As Double
end_r = A.ListObjects(1).ListRows.Count + A.ListObjects(1).ListRows(1).Range.Row - 1
Dim e() As Double
ReDim e(r To end_r, 0)
    Do Until r > end_r
        If A.Rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            e(r, 0) = 1
        Else
            e(r, 0) = 0
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    A.Cells(A.ListObjects(1).ListRows(1).Range.Row, _
    A.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).Range.Column).Select
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        If Err <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "No Filter Detected, Macro Aborted"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range(Cells(A.ListObjects(1).ListRows(1).Range.Row, C), Cells(end_r, C)) = e
    A.ListObjects.Item(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    A.ListObjects.Item(1).Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range(A.ListObjects.Item(1).Name & "[F]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With A.ListObjects.Item(1).Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
   'A.Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name & "[F]").AutoFilter Criteria1:="1"
   A.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=C, Criteria1:="1"
End Sub
```